# Why will my remove function find strings but not ints?

Tags: java, generics

We are working on generics which requires us to have an array of AnyType (the driver implements an array of strings then integers). One of the functions is a boolean function called 'remove' which finds 'x' and removes it, then it returns true. It has no issues finding and removing a string but can't seem to find ints. Why is this?

the code is

```
public boolean remove(AnyType x)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == x)
        {
            for(int j = i; j < length - 1; j++)
            {
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
            }
            length--;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you should use `equals` instead of `==`, it will not work with Strings either if you try to `remove(new String("aaa"))`

Comment: hoaz was correct, thank you hoaz if you are seeing this

Answer (score 0):

user hoaz's answer fixed the problem. using .equals instead of == was the issue. fixed code looks like this

```
public boolean remove(AnyType x)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i].equals(x))
        {
            for(int j = i; j < length - 1; j++)
            {
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
            }
            length--;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This question was already solved, but I'd just like to provide additional information.

The reason for this issue was using `==` to compare rather than `.equals`. This is a problem because the `==` equality operator compares based on memory reference, so for example, `1 == 1` is true because `1` is a primitive stored in one place in memory then referenced as needed, whereas two objects would only return true if they were the exact same instance of the object.

`.equals`, on the other hand, is a method often overridden from `Object` to compare the object's fields to eachother, and if not overridden, it would fallback to using `==`, so it is almost always the preferable method of comparison.

More info: [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)